# Proper usage of "I wish it would....... so I ......"

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> "I wish it would rain so I hang my dirty clothes outside"

Or should it be more like:

> "I wish it would rain, so I would hang my dirty clothes outside"

Are both of them correct?

Comment: Your second sentence is correct (I'd use "could hang") though I'd rather use a washing machine.

Comment: There are two patterns you can follow: I wish it would ... so I could ..., OR I wish it would ... so I can ....

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you mean to stress the purpose of hanging the clothes outside (to let them get washed under the rain), using "so that" would be more appropriate:

> I wish it would rain so that I could hang my dirty clothes outside

(to have them washed).

Using just "so", you would mean sooner the result you're expecting from the falling rain--to wash the dirty clothes:

> I wish it would rain so I could have my dirty clothes washed

(on the clotheslines outside).

Answer (score -1):

The first one would be correct except for a missing comma—although it's used in an unusual "literary" sense. (More on this later.)

There are several different common ways you could phrase it:

> **I wish** it would rain, (and) so **I will hang** my dirty clothes outside [in case it does].
>   **I had wished** it would rain, (and) so **I** *(had)* **hung** [or *hanged*] my dirty clothes outside [in case it did].

The way these are phrased makes the interpretation a little difficult. They can be rephrased to make the meaning clearer:

> Because **I wish** it would rain, **I will hang** my dirty clothes outside [in case it does].
>   Because **I had wished** it would rain, **I** *(had)* **hung** [or *hanged*] my dirty clothes outside [in case it did].

Back to your original examples.

You could say:

> **I wish** it would rain so that my dirty clothes **could get** washed.

Without the comma, the second part of the sentence is subordinate to the first part—it explains why you wish it would rain.

But without the comma in your example:

> **I wish** it would rain so [that] **I hang** my dirty clothes outside.

This doesn't make sense.

With the addition of a comma, the hanging of the clothes is no longer a reason for the wish, but an action that happens in addition to the wish.

> **I wish** it would rain, [and] so **I hang** my clothes outside.

---

I say that this phrasing is "literary" because writing everything in the present tense is normally only used for narrative effect:

> **I walk** to the door and **open it**. **I can't** believe what **I see**, and so **I jump** back in surprise.

It's not wrong, but more typically it would be written in the past tense (especially outside of a literature):

> **I walked** to the door and **opened it**. I **couldn't believe** what **I saw**, and so **I jumped** back in surprise.

---

One final note. Although again not wrong, it would be more common to use **hope** or **expect** in these sentences than **wish**.

With **wish**, the the sentence could be interpreted to mean that you think that hanging your clothes outside will *cause* it to rain. But, in fact, you most likely mean that you just want to take advantage of the rain *if* it happens—and you'd like it to happen. So, **hope** or **expect** has better mental associations.